# elasticsearch migrate 503 - cluster_block_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 7.9 and I am trying to migrate from remote cluster to local cluster.
When I am running the post reindex in postman I am getting the following error:

````
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "cluster_block_exception",
                "reason": "blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];",
                "suppressed": [
                    {
                        "type": "master_not_discovered_exception",
                        "reason": "ClusterBlockException[index [gil_support_log] blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "type": "cluster_block_exception",
        "reason": "blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];",
        "suppressed": [
            {
                "type": "master_not_discovered_exception",
                "reason": "ClusterBlockException[index [gil_support_log] blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];]",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "cluster_block_exception",
                    "reason": "index [gil_support_log] blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 503
}```

Can someone help me understand what is the problem?
````

Comment: please share more information. how many node do you have? how many master? did cluster work fine?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the log from the master node.

```
/var/log/elasticsearch
```

In my case, I discover that one of my nodes cannot connect to the node that I got this error. And then it was removed from the cluster.

I was config some security rules to keep the connection alive and everything worked back